# How can I select an element by Id?

Tags: playwright

I wonder how I can access an element by ID. I want to submit a form.

- `await page.click("id= 'next'");` --> not possible
- `await page.getByRole('button', { id: 'next' }).click();` --> does not compile
- `await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();` --> work but is language dependent

Selecting elements by their ID seems the most robust to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are missing in the first example are the square brackets, instead of:

```
await page.click("id= 'next'");
```

you should do this:

```
await page.click("[id='next']");
```

alternatively, you can use the shorthand version like mentioned in the other answer

Comment: This also works when the id has a . in it, which would cause trouble with the # approach.

Answer (score 23):

You can do something like this:

```
await page.locator("#YourId").click()
```

or just

```
await page.click("#YourId");
```

Playwright recommends some [predefined locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#quick-guide) so you could also check if some off those fit your use case.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple ways to locate element by id in Playwright:

1. **Using `page.locator` with [CSS Selector](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-locator):**

   ```js
   const element = await page.locator('#yourElementId');
   ```
2. **Using `page.locator` with [XPath](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#xpath-locator):**

   ```js
   const element = await page.locator('//*[@id="yourElementId"]');
   ```
3. **Using `page.locator` with `id` [Attribute Locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#id-data-testid-data-test-id-data-test-selectors):** (Not Recommended)

   ```js
   const element = await page.locator('id=yourElementId');
   ```

   Note - **Attribute selectors are not CSS selectors!** for more info follow the docs link.

FYI: playwright consider those locators above as "other locators",
Playwright recommend using their [user-visible locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators), such as `getByRole`, `getByText`, `getByPlaceholder`:

> We recommend prioritizing *user-visible locators* like text or accessible role instead of using CSS/XPath that are tied to the implementation and could break when the page changes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Set a custom test id attribute

If all of your elements have Id defined as general test automation strategy, you may configure an custom id attribute to locate all your elements.

By default, page.getByTestId() will locate elements based on the data-testid attribute, but you can configure it in your test config or by calling selectors.setTestIdAttribute().

Set the test id to use a custom data attribute for your tests.

```
//playwright.config
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    testIdAttribute: 'data-pw'
  }
});
```

In your html you can now use data-pw as your test id instead of the default data-testid.

And then locate the element as you would normally do:

```
await page.getByTestId('directions').click();
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-test-id